# How to functional test a mule flow in isolation

Tags: mule, functional-testing

I've several flows in my `Mule 3.3.0` application, some of which are inter-linked (web-service end-point is listening on one flow, it does some processing and routes the payload into different JMS queues, inbound JMS queues are listening on different flows).

I've a `functional-test` for the web service end-point flow which works well but I want to test this flow in isolation of other flows. Is it possible to disable message listeners for other flows?

Answer (score 0):

You could try stopping all the flows that are not involved in the test programatically, as part of the test setup.

Comment: With this, you get all the flows:
`muleContext.getRegistry().lookupFlowConstructs()`


You go through that list, casting to Flow, and call stop() on each element except the ones you want active.